# cakephp index.ctp file syntax error

Tags: cakephp

It is showing me an error:-

> Error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)  File
>   C:\Windows\System32\myapp1\src\Template\Myapp1\index.ctp  Line: 50

Line 50 is as follows:-

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List <%= $this->_pluralHumanName($alias) %>'),['controller '] => '<%= $details['controller'] %>','action' => 'index']) ?></li>
```

What do i need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Routing... you wrote ['controller']=>

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List <%= $this->_pluralHumanName($alias) %>'),['controller '] => '<%= $details['controller'] %>','action' => 'index']) ?></li>
```

Should be,

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List <%= $this->_pluralHumanName($alias) %>'),['controller' => '<%= $details['controller'] %>','action' => 'index']) ?></li>
```

Comment: it says :    Error: syntax error, unexpected 'controller' (T_STRING), expecting ']' 
File C:\Windows\System32\myapp1\src\Template\Myapp1\index.ctp 
Line: 51

Answer (score 0):

> it says : Error: syntax error, unexpected 'controller' (T_STRING),
>   expecting ']' File
>   C:\Windows\System32\myapp1\src\Template\Myapp1\index.ctp Line: 51

Please check index.ctp, ']' is not given. Or share your code again